# How can I change the NavBar title text color in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, swift4

When developing in swift 3 I was used to write:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orange]
```

putting this in AppDelegate would change all the UINavbars' title color to orange.

Now I want to do the same with Swift 4 and iOS 11.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the UINavigationBar title color by setting the `foregroundColor` property on `titleTextAttributes`.

As documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar):

> The  titleTextAttributes  property specifies the attributes for
>   displaying the bar’s title text. You can specify the font, text color,
>   text shadow color, and text shadow offset for the title in the text
>   attributes dictionary using the  font ,  foregroundColor , and  shadow
>   keys, respectively.

So you will have the same effect doing this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.orange]
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4.1 Changing navigation bar title color**

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        //To change iOS 11 navigationBar largeTitle color

        UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    } else {
        // for default navigation bar title color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
```

**Swift 4.2+ Changing navigation bar title color**

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        //To change iOS 11 navigationBar largeTitle color

        UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    } else {
        // for default navigation bar title color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
```

Comment: NSAttributedStringKey has been updated to NSAttributedString.Key

Answer (score 5):

App delegate swift 4.2

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
 UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xED6E19)
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(hex: 0xED6E19)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.orange]
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 implementation for both large and regular titles:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func setTitleForgroundTitleColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): color]
    }

    func setLargeTitleColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        self.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): color]
    }

    func setAllTitleColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        setTitleForgroundTitleColor(color)
        setLargeTitleColor(color)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the navigation bar title color by using this code

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
fileprivate func convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary(_ input: [String: Any]?) -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? {
        guard let input = input else { return nil }
        return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map { key, value in (NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: key), value)})
}
```

Usage

```
   // Set Navigation bar Title color

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue : UIColor.white])
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5 if Someone is Looking around like I was :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(displayP3Red: 84/255, green: 93/255, blue: 118/255, alpha: 1)]
```

Comment: For those landing here for iOS15 you will need to add the above value to the `UINavigationBarAppearance` and set this on your navigation bar.  The `UINavigationBarAppearance` was introduced in iOS13, (I haven’t tested 13 or 14)